# Matlab2tikz and alignment: i need help

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matlab, matlab2tikz

I made matlab2tikz convert two matlab graps into .tex files, the first image generated the following code:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
xmin=1,
xmax=1023,
xminorticks=true,
ymode=log,
ymin=0.000605918006841938,
ymax=1,
yminorticks=true,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={$\text{Mesh uniforme, }\alpha\text{ = 5/3}$},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.139792014524203\\
7   0.072479842055017\\
15  0.0370157945331386\\
31  0.0187746232975879\\
63  0.00948601785348729\\
127 0.00478085586105112\\
255 0.00240517988982091\\
511 0.00120838462520132\\
1023    0.000606477293609539\\
};
\addlegendentry{Quadratura}

\addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.138651919621344\\
7   0.0720316322486566\\
15  0.036847197754512\\
31  0.0187112162712767\\
63  0.00946188033580206\\
127 0.00477154931108847\\
255 0.00240155605217295\\
511 0.00120696404181309\\
1023    0.000605918006841938\\
};
\addlegendentry{Calcolo esatto}

\addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.25\\
7   0.125\\
15  0.0625\\
31  0.03125\\
63  0.015625\\
127 0.0078125\\
255 0.00390625\\
511 0.001953125\\
1023    0.0009765625\\
};
\addlegendentry{h}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5.833in,
height=4.375in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

and here's what the second image gave as result

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
xmin=1,
xmax=1023,
xminorticks=true,
ymode=log,
ymin=0.0009765625,
ymax=1,
yminorticks=true,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={$\text{Mesh uniforme, }\alpha\text{ = 10}$},
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.197209957231232\\
7   0.125510101886693\\
15  0.0652111253628991\\
31  0.0328432469804731\\
63  0.0164486751222861\\
127 0.00822763156405254\\
255 0.00411422476433522\\
511 0.00205716341817707\\
1023    0.00102858808587584\\
};
\addlegendentry{Quadratura}

\addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.153395370790933\\
7   0.112257863184386\\
15  0.0631720206082784\\
31  0.0325749327203\\
63  0.0164147037161947\\
127 0.00822337153398153\\
255 0.00411369183465216\\
511 0.00205709678865042\\
1023    0.00102857975676872\\
};
\addlegendentry{Calcolo esatto}

\addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3   0.25\\
7   0.125\\
15  0.0625\\
31  0.03125\\
63  0.015625\\
127 0.0078125\\
255 0.00390625\\
511 0.001953125\\
1023    0.0009765625\\
};
\addlegendentry{h}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5.833in,
height=4.375in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Now, i succeded in showing this two graph in my latex main thanks to the following instructions:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{Error_uniform_53}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{Error_uniform_10}
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
```

Where `Error_uniform_53` is the name of the first .tex file and `Error_uniform_10` is the name i gave to the second .tex file.
I would like to have these two graphs placed side by side, i've already tried using subfigure but it seems not to work, probably because of the tikzpiucture. Can someone help me?
I leave here a MWE (keep in mind the name i gave to the .tex files containing the pictures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{Error_uniform_53}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{Error_uniform_10}
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try to insert code of your pictures on the following way:     `\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.48\hline}
    \input{Error_uniform_53}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.48\hline}
    \input{Error_uniform_53}
    \caption{Caption 2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}`.

Comment: "it seems not to work" isn't a very actionable description of the problem… Please explain what happens exactly and what you expected.

Comment: @Miyase when i try to use it, the figures overlap or it doesn't compile at all
@Zarko I tried your code but the figures are still not aligned horizontally and the compiler gives me the following errors: ```Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).``` and ```Misplaced \noalign.```

Comment: Welcome. // Please help us all save time and make your main code compile once we‘ve copied it. I.e. start with ˋ\documentclassˋ and end with ˋ\end{document}ˋ and we can skip half of all speculations …

Comment: @MS-SPO got it, i created a new file with just the bare minimun in order to compile, but it still doesn't work.
However, i would like to thank everyone for the welcoming messages, very appreciates :)

Comment: @Davide, please replace the code in your question with your MWE, so we can have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a way to do it. I'm afraid, you need to rework the generated `tikz`-pictures, as you can't `\input` them directly without creating layout problems. I.e. comment out the parts mentioned below, first.

Let's have a look.

#### Preamble

Working with yours was ... nasty. So this one works in the context given below, where the ams-packages are ONLY needed for the title created inside `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Package `caption` is needed, as minipage doesn't use a float environment. Use like:

```
\captionof{figure}{Cap 2}\label{fig:2}
```

#### Using minipages

Similar to what @Zarko proposed, the structure is:

```
 \begin{minipage}{7cm}% ~~~ minipage 1 ~~~~~~~~~~
 ... // first drawing
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill
 \begin{minipage}{7cm}% ~~~ minipage 2 ~~~~~~~~~~
 ... // second drawing
 \end{minipage}
```

Now, my use of the `minipage` environment can certainly be improved, while this one works.

#### Let's turn to the drama, the 2 generated files

In brief, that code provides some unpleasant surprises in your intended context, though they work fine individually. So in order to just `\input` them, you need to comment them out a little. My code below just copies both parts, to better show, what's obsolete, even causing trouble.

Meaningless and controproductive changes to layout, scale, psoitioning; just get rid of it:

```
        %width=4.521in,% <<< all these give unwanted shifts and scalings
        %height=3.566in,
        %at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
        %scale only axis,
```

This part at the end is crazy, causing even more hard to localize problems; so, get rid of it:

```
        %\begin{axis}[% <<< these are simply not good
        %width=5.833in,
        %height=4.375in,
        %at={(0in,0in)},
        %scale only axis,
        %xmin=0,
        %xmax=1,
        %ymin=0,
        %ymax=1,
        %axis line style={draw=none},
        %ticks=none,
        %axis x line*=bottom,
        %axis y line*=left
        %]
        %\end{axis}
```

Kindly also check this innocent line at the beginning of each generated plot, which you have to add or modify for the scaling:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,transform shape]
```

Balance this scaling-factor with the widths you use for the minipages.

#### Result + code

[image: plots]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
 % ~~~ using 2 minipage-environments, with a \hfill inbetween ~~~~~
 \begin{minipage}{7cm}% ~~~ minipage 1 ~~~~~~~~~~
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
    \definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,transform shape]
        
      \begin{axis}[%
        %width=4.521in,% <<< all these give unwanted shifts and scalings
        %height=3.566in,
        %at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
        %scale only axis,
        xmode=log,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=1023,
        xminorticks=true,
        ymode=log,
        ymin=0.000605918006841938,
        ymax=1,
        yminorticks=true,
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        title style={font=\bfseries},
        title={$\text{Mesh uniforme, }\alpha\text{ = 5/3}$},
        legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
        ]
        \addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.139792014524203\\
        7   0.072479842055017\\
        15  0.0370157945331386\\
        31  0.0187746232975879\\
        63  0.00948601785348729\\
        127 0.00478085586105112\\
        255 0.00240517988982091\\
        511 0.00120838462520132\\
        1023    0.000606477293609539\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Quadratura}
        
        \addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.138651919621344\\
        7   0.0720316322486566\\
        15  0.036847197754512\\
        31  0.0187112162712767\\
        63  0.00946188033580206\\
        127 0.00477154931108847\\
        255 0.00240155605217295\\
        511 0.00120696404181309\\
        1023    0.000605918006841938\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Calcolo esatto}
        
        \addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.25\\
        7   0.125\\
        15  0.0625\\
        31  0.03125\\
        63  0.015625\\
        127 0.0078125\\
        255 0.00390625\\
        511 0.001953125\\
        1023    0.0009765625\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{h}
        
  \end{axis}
        
        %\begin{axis}[% <<< these are simply not good
        %width=5.833in,
        %height=4.375in,
        %at={(0in,0in)},
        %scale only axis,
        %xmin=0,
        %xmax=1,
        %ymin=0,
        %ymax=1,
        %axis line style={draw=none},
        %ticks=none,
        %axis x line*=bottom,
        %axis y line*=left
        %]
        %\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \captionof{figure}{Cap 1}\label{fig:2}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill
 \begin{minipage}{7cm}% ~~~ minipage 2 ~~~~~~~~~~
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
    \definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,transform shape]

      \begin{axis}[%
        %width=4.521in,
        %height=3.566in,
        %at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
        %scale only axis,
        xmode=log,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=1023,
        xminorticks=true,
        ymode=log,
        ymin=0.0009765625,
        ymax=1,
        yminorticks=true,
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        title style={font=\bfseries},
        title={$\text{Mesh uniforme, }\alpha\text{ = 10}$},
        legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
        ]
        \addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.197209957231232\\
        7   0.125510101886693\\
        15  0.0652111253628991\\
        31  0.0328432469804731\\
        63  0.0164486751222861\\
        127 0.00822763156405254\\
        255 0.00411422476433522\\
        511 0.00205716341817707\\
        1023    0.00102858808587584\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Quadratura}
        
        \addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=asterisk, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.153395370790933\\
        7   0.112257863184386\\
        15  0.0631720206082784\\
        31  0.0325749327203\\
        63  0.0164147037161947\\
        127 0.00822337153398153\\
        255 0.00411369183465216\\
        511 0.00205709678865042\\
        1023    0.00102857975676872\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{Calcolo esatto}
        
        \addplot [color=mycolor3, dashed]
          table[row sep=crcr]{%
        3   0.25\\
        7   0.125\\
        15  0.0625\\
        31  0.03125\\
        63  0.015625\\
        127 0.0078125\\
        255 0.00390625\\
        511 0.001953125\\
        1023    0.0009765625\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{h}

      \end{axis}

    %\begin{axis}[%
    %width=5.833in,
    %height=4.375in,
    %at={(0in,0in)},
    %scale only axis,
    %xmin=0,
    %xmax=1,
    %ymin=0,
    %ymax=1,
    %axis line style={draw=none},
    %ticks=none,
    %axis x line*=bottom,
    %axis y line*=left
    %]
    %\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \captionof{figure}{Cap 2}\label{fig:2}

 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the pacience, your solution is working just fine.

Comment: @Davide, thank you and great 

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but what if i wanted to have one caption in common for the two figures instead of two different captions?

Comment: Without having tried it, I‘d delete one of the \captionof statements and move the other behind the last minipage. Perhaps it‘s a good idea then to wrap all (2 minipages and \captionof) into a center environment.

Comment: Working fine, but if i wrap all into a center environment, the figures are aligned vertically instead of horizontally. Did some tries and it aligns the figures horizontally if wrapped in a figure environment.

Comment: Reducing the scaling factor should help (see my balancing remark in the answer)